# jquery validation css change effecting field too?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

How avoid jquery validation css to field too. I have a dropdown. If validation fails. dropdown text color also changing to red. How to avoid that? and also validation error message show under field. suppose to next to field.

[image]

```
class
    .validationError {
        color: #ff0000;
    }


<select class="form-control validationError" data-val="true" data-val-required="The CommunicationLocation field is required." id="CommunicationLocation" name="CommunicationLocation" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <option value="HOME">Personal</option>
 <option value="WORK">Work/University</option>
</select>
<label id="CommunicationLocation-error" class="validationError" for="CommunicationLocation">Required</label>
```

script

```
 $.validator.addMethod("selectNone",
        function (value, element) {
            alert(value);
            if (value == 'Select')
                return false;
            else
                return true;
    });
$("#frmEmail").validate({
    rules: {
        CommunicationLocation: {
            required: true
        }

    },
    messages: {
        CommunicationLocation: {
            required: "Required"
        }
    },
   errorClass:"validationError",
```

Comment: Change the CSS rule from `.validationError` to `label.validationError`

Comment: you need to remove error class `.removeClass('error');`

Comment: @gon250, why would he want to do that?

Comment: @Sparky Well.. you are right, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

1. [According to your HTML, the `<label>` element **will be** on the right side of the `<select>` element](http://jsfiddle.net/afeag0sy/).  There is nothing in the JavaScript or HTML shown to us that would make it appear underneath.  HOWEVER, if your parent container is not wide enough, then this content will automatically wrap to the next line.  You'll need to inspect your DOM and fix the width of the relevant parent container to allow the `<select>` and `<label>` to appear side by side.  Otherwise, you'll have to show us the actual code that causes this problem.
2. If you don't want the input element to use the same CSS properties as the error message container, then your CSS target needs to be more specific.  Use `label.validationError` to target only the `label` containing the error message.

   ```
   label.validationError {
       color: #ff0000;
   }
   ```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/afeag0sy/**